# PlayFramework form validation with additional constraints

Tags: java, scala, validation, playframework, playframework-2.6

Disclaimer: Using PlayFramework 2.6.0-M4 here!

I display a form and want to add additional constraint that some strings are forbidden for a given field.

Now I have two problems with this:

```
def create() = Action(parse.form(createUserForm))
  {
   implicit request =>
      val formData: CreateUserData = request.body

      if(validate(formData).isDefined)
      {
        userRepository.create(formData.name, formData.dummy)

        Ok(s"Here should go success, if user was created: $formData")
      } else {
        BadRequest("No means no!")
      }
  }

  case class CreateUserData(name: String, dummy: Boolean)

  private val createUserForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> text,
      "dummy" -> boolean
    )(CreateUserData.apply)(CreateUserData.unapply)
    verifying("Failed form constraints!", fields => fields match
    {
      case data => validate(data).isDefined
    })
  )

  private def validate(formData: CreatUserData): Option[CreatUserData] =
  {
    ReservedWords.filter(
      _.equalsIgnoreCase(formData.name)
    ).isEmpty match
    {
      case true => Some(formData)
      case false => None
    }
  }
```

1) `Ok(s"Here should go success, if user was created: $formData").as("text/html")` works in case the provided data is valid, BUT in case the user entered a forbidden name:

a) No user is created (GOOD)
b) `BadRequest("No means no!")` never gets returned! (Although I get a http 400 response, just empty)

I don't understand why b) happens.

Furthermore I wanted to follow https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms

and instead write the code like this:

```
def create() = Action(parse.form(createUserForm))
{
  implicit request =>

    createUserForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors =>
      {
        BadRequest("Errors: " + formWithErrors.errors).as("text/html")
      },
      formData =>
      {
        userRepository.create(formData.name, formData.dummy)
        Redirect(s"/")
      }
    )
}
```

But sadly this leads to errors on EVERY post request, even the ones that are totally valid:

> Errors: List(FormError(name,List(error.required),List()))

What am I doing wrong?

edit: To clarify what I mean by "total valid request" I give an example on what returns above error.

`name=Teolha&dummy=true` sent as post request.

Actually it does not matter what I enter, but the HTML5 part of the (rendered) form makes sure that I have to enter something. What I would expect was `Ok` in case of anything that is *NOT* on the list of `ReservedWords`, else `BadRequest`

edit2: May this be because of the default filters?

Those are running in play 2.6:

```
play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
```

I ask, because I am **NOT** using Twirl here (but ScalaTags) to render the form! So maybe I am missing some implicit stuff that the twirl implementation would cover (a token or something)?

Comment: `Errors: List(FormError(name,List(error.required),List()))` suggests that you're not posting a name. Can you please show what exactly you're posting?

Comment: I added an example for a "totally valid request" I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: I would log the `request` object just to see what the controller is actually getting.

Comment: It is logged. What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: btw, rename `ReservedWords` to `ForbiddenNames` - it discurage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct behavior:

https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.0-M4/ScalaForms

```
val userPost = Action(parse.form(userForm)) { implicit request =>
```

> In the failure case, the default behavior is to return an empty BadRequest response.

And next:

> You can override this behavior with your own logic. For instance, the following code is completely equivalent to the preceding one using bindFromRequest and fold.

```
val userPostWithErrors = Action(parse.form(userForm, onErrors = (formWithErrors: Form[UserData]) => {
  implicit val messages = messagesApi.preferred(Seq(Lang.defaultLang))
  BadRequest(views.html.user(formWithErrors))
})) { implicit request =>
  val userData = request.body
  val newUser = models.User(userData.name, userData.age)
  val id = models.User.create(newUser)
  Redirect(routes.Application.home(id))
}
```

**In your case**

`Action(parse.form(createUserForm))` calls validation before you call it in your code (`if(validate(formData).isDefined)` is redundant). So it calls validation, validation is not success and play returns an empty bad request.

**Fix:** process error in `onError` handler of `parse.form` function. i.e. `Action(parse.form(createUserForm, onErrors =  ...`

**Second question**

You call `Action(parse.form(createUserForm))` - it process form, then you call `createUserForm.bindFromRequest` but form already processed, so you got an empty form. That is correct as well.

**Fix:** remove `parse.form(createUserForm)` so you must have only `Action()`